# Should I be using a User Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

So basically what I want to try to do, is make a simple form that the user can enter login information into (to log them into a mysql DB. Then the program will query the database, display the info, and the user can do some manipulation.

What I want to avoid is having a bunch of popup window forms (one to log in, one to select the query for the database, etc)...

So what I was thinking was in my mainform, have "sub forms" embedded into it. I was reading up about this, and discovered most people said it is better to nest user controls into forms, vs. other forms.

Just so you can see what I am talking about, this is a VERY basic skeleton of what I want it to look like:

[image]

As you can see, very simple, just instead of having all the popup boxes, embedding the user input stuff into the right side of the form

So, should I indeed be using  user controls for this?

If so, I am having some issues with getting values back to the main form from the user control (because there is no showDialog() method or dialog results from user controls, so I do not know when the user has entered all their log in data for the sql server, for example.)

I have attempted to use call by reference to pass in the values to the usercontrol which I want to be set BY the user control - but I havent been able to make that work...

Anyways, If I should be using a userControl here vs. a userForm, how should I be getting the user input back to the mainform??

Comment: it's not necessary to put "C#" in the title. It's already in the tags.

Comment: ok...I will remember for next time thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e63s4df3.aspx).

The pattern I usually use for communicating information back to the main form is subclassing Panel for my embedded content and creating properties on this subclass for each of the things I want to pass back to my main form.

Example:

```
public class LoginPanel : Panel
{
    public string Username { get; set;}
    ...
}
```

If I want to get fancy and do things like automatically check to see if the host is valid or the credentials will authenticate I might also add a `Changed` event to the `Panel` that fires whenever there's a change to the contents of any of the inputs it contains. I would then add a handler for this event on my main form.

If you want to get really fancy (I would do this if I were going to create a reusable User Control) you can do all the connection and authentication in your subclass, have only a `SqlConnection` property and fire a `Connected` event.

Something like this:

```
public class LoginPanel : Panel
{
    // A property returning a valid connection when
    // connected, null otherwise.
    public SqlConnection connection { get; set;}
    ...

    // An event that clients can use to be notified whenever 
    // a connection is made.
    public event EventHandler Connected;

    // Invoke the Connected event; called whenever a successful 
    // connection is made
    protected virtual void OnConnected(EventArgs e) 
    {
       if (Connected!= null)
          Connected(this, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I will try using a panel...that actually makes lots of sense. The only part I am still a little hazy on is how do I pass the information from the panel back to the main program? Because the main program will not know when the values of the textbox are entered correctly...I could have a button in the Panel, but how would the main button know when the button is pressed? Thanks!!

Comment: @Toadums If you like this answer, you should upvote and accept! :-)

Comment: I understand how to pass back the values (like in the first code snippet you gave), the problem is how does the main program (which holds the panel) know when there are valid values?

Comment: @Toadums That's where adding the extra event comes in. You add an event to your subclass which fires whenever you want and add an event handler for it on your main form. Alternatively, if the button is on your main form, you can just check the values when the button event handler fires.

Comment: Hmm, I think I like the idea of the first one more (having an event which fires)...I have never done that before, but I will try to make it work :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use custom user controls when you are going to be doing the same thing again and again in different places throughout the application.  For instance, if you had multiple places in your app where the user needed to enter login information, then you would want to make a user control to encapsulate that functionality so that you only need to program the logic and look once, not over and over again.  The complexity of the app is increased, but the value in not having to write redundant code is far greater than the minor complexity in

In places where you only are performing a certain function one time, however, adding a user control adds complexity to the app without adding the anti-redundancy value, and so should be avoided.

I'll leave the "how-to" implementation part of the question to someone else.